# PySpark 2.4: TypeError: Column is not iterable (with F.col() usage)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following gives me a `TypeError: Column is not iterable` exception:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark_sesn.createDataFrame([Row(col0 = 10,
                                     col2 = 'ten',
                                     col3 = 10.0),])

df.withColumn('key',        F.lit('1')) # This succeeds.
df.withColumn(F.col('key'), F.lit('1')) # This causes an exception. <---- TypeError
```

You might be wondering why I want to use the second variation at all. It's because I need to access the `.alias()` method to add `metadata` to that column, like so:

```
df.withColumn(F.col('key').alias('key', metadata={'foo':'bar'}), F.lit('1'))
```

How do we get the second variation to work and/or insert the `metadata` needed? Keep in mind that the real `DataFrame` already exists (meaning, I can't create one from scratch like I did in this simple example).

Thank you! =:)

Comment: you could probably save the intermediate result in a dataframe and then use `.alias` once the column is available. The reason for the error is `col()` expects an actual column name from the dataframe, not any other string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`withColumn` requires the first parameter to be a string, so don't think the second option can work; You might just use `select` to add a new column with alias:

```
df.select("*", F.lit(1).alias("key", metadata={"foo": "bar"})).show()
+----+----+----+---+
|col0|col2|col3|key|
+----+----+----+---+
|  10| ten|10.0|  1|
+----+----+----+---+
```

Or you can use `alias` on `F.lit` when using `withColumn`:

```
df.withColumn("key", F.lit(1).alias(None, metadata={"foo": "bar"})).show()
+----+----+----+---+
|col0|col2|col3|key|
+----+----+----+---+
|  10| ten|10.0|  1|
+----+----+----+---+
```